# What is the difference between "mortuary" and "morgue"?

Tags: word-usage, transatlantic-differences

I want to know what's the place in a hospital called where bodies are kept until the time families or the police claim or identify them. Is it "morgue" or "mortuary"?

Also, what are the differences between the two places. I understand both places involve bodies but what differentiates them and what are their duties. Thanks.

Comment: If this is not clear from the dictionary definitions [mortuary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mortuary) [morgue](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/morgue), please explain your uncertainty.  There are some dialect differences.

Comment: [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgue) *A **morgue OR mortuary** (in a hospital or elsewhere) is a place used for the storage of human corpses* (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that 'morgue' is mainly, but not exclusively, American English, and 'mortuary' is mainly British English. Both words mean (in a hospital or elsewhere) a place used for the storage of human corpses awaiting identification (ID), removal for autopsy, respectful burial, cremation or other methods of disposal.